# ASP.NET MVC 5 send a model and model list to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Models:

```
public class Room
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Building
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public Room room {get;set;}
    public List<Room> rooms { get; set; }
    public Building  building { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class BuildingController : Controller
{
    // GET: Building
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Here I save the model in DB
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Test_asp.net.Models.ViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h2>Create Building</h2>
    <div class="form-group clone form-inline">
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.building.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.building.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.room.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Name = "[0]Room" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.building.Name);
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.room.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Name="[1]Room" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.building.Name)
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

View output:

```
<form action="/Building/create" method="post">    <h2>Create Building</h2>
    <div class="form-group clone form-inline">
        <div>
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="building_Name" name="building.Name" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="building.Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input Name="[0]Room" class="text-box single-line" id="room_Name" name="room.Name" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="building.Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>;
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input Name="[1]Room" class="text-box single-line" id="room_Name" name="room.Name" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="building.Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The method create in the controller should receive the viewModel with a building object and a List rooms. Actually I receive a `Building` object and I don't know why the the list of rooms is null?

Comment: change ``[0]Room`` to like  ``viewModel.rooms[0].Name``

Comment: Ok perfect. Now if i remove a item in a list, how can i replace the correct index order in the List rooms ? I clone with jquery one div container , search the index number and replace the number with index + 1. If a item deleted the index number is missing.

Comment: @axurSdaffv Use <input type="hidden" name="rooms.Index" value="ROOM" /> and rooms[ROOM].Name in your view. I am going to update my answer

Comment: Ok, if i use rooms[ROOM].Name  the receive this error message: The name 'Room' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the input names from

```
@Name="[0]Room"
```

to

```
rooms[0].Name
```

You have to include the name of the list property `rooms`, because your property in the Action method is not `List<Room>`, but `ViewModel viewModel`.

Since you want to remove items in the list, instead of using consequential indexes 0, 1, 2.. etc (which should be unbroken) use Indexes:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rooms.Index" value="AAA" />
<input type="text" name="rooms[AAA].Name" value="Room 1" />

<input type="hidden" name="rooms.Index" value="AAB" />
<input type="text" name="rooms[AAB].Name" value="Room 2" />
```

And you can generate the value of the Index on the fly.

You can read more from  Phil Haack's post [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Comment: I gess it should be `rooms[i].Name` not `viewModel.rooms[AAA].Name`.

Comment: @teovankot The idea here is that the index value does not matter. It could be "AAA", or "213123213" etc. It just have to be unique and to match the input's name in the square brackets. Please see the link for clarification - http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/  (The section with title Non-Sequential Indices).

Comment: When i use the code like in the example, why the List rooms is null ?                                                                 <input type="hidden" name="rooms.Index" value="ROOM" />
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.rooms[123].Name)

Comment: Update, i change the value in input hidden to 123. I fill out 2 inputs fields, i received in the controler just the first item.   <input type="hidden" name="rooms.Index" value="123" />

Comment: The first one is AAA the second should be AAB. If you want 123, use something else for the second 124 for example

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Dictionary with random keys (ticks, guid etc.)

Models:

```
    public class Room
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public Room room {get;set;}
        public Dictionary <string, Room> rooms { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<div>
foreach(var room in rooms){
    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.rooms[room.Key].Id)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.rooms[room.Key].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        <a href="#" class="remove" data-id="@Model.rooms[room.Key].Id">Remove</a>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public List<Room> rooms { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IList<Room> rooms { get; set; }
```

and then use

```
  @for (int i=0; i<=3;i++)
    {
        <div> 
            @Html.Hidden("rooms.Index", null,new { Value = i})
            @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.rooms[i].Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.rooms[i].Name);
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
        </div>
    }
```

Rendering non sequential indexes from 1 in case your user remove any row.

```
 @for (int i=1; i<=3;i++)
    {
        <div> 
            @Html.Hidden("rooms.Index", null,new { Value = i})
            @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.rooms[i].Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.rooms[i].Name);
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
        </div>
    }
```

This is the html you will be generated

```
            <input value="1" id="rooms_Index" name="rooms.Index" type="hidden">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="rooms_1__Name" name="rooms[1].Name" value="" type="text">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="rooms[1].Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>;
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>

            <input value="2" id="rooms_Index" name="rooms.Index" type="hidden">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="rooms_2__Name" name="rooms[2].Name" value="" type="text">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="rooms[2].Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>;
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>

            <input value="3" id="rooms_Index" name="rooms.Index" type="hidden">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="rooms_3__Name" name="rooms[3].Name" value="" type="text">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="rooms[3].Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>;
            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
```